# Whats going on in this quadratic?

Tags: quadratics

### The Question

If the equation $sin^2x -k\space sinx -3 =0$ has exactly two distinct real roots in $[0,\pi]$, then find the values of $k$.

### The Answer

Let $f(t)=t^2 -kt -3$, where $t=sinx$.
Since equation has exactly two distinct  real roots in $[0,\pi]$, $f(t)=0$ must have exactly one root in $(0,1)$.
Now, $f(0)=-3$.
So, we must have $f(1)=-k-2>0$
or $k<-2$

### My Question

Why does $f(t)=0$ have **exactly** one root in $(0,1)$ ? Why not $2$ ? I guess this might be a trivial question but I really don't get it.

Comment: Unless $t=1$, the equation $t=\sin x$ has two solutions in $[0,\pi]$. Thus, you need a unique solution for $t$ in $[0,1)$ to have two solutions for $x$. Since $t=0$ is never a solution, it is enough to consider $t\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thank you so much!