# What are possible values of $k$ if $\sin^2 x - k \sin x -3 = 0$ has exactly two distinct real roots in $[0, \pi]$

Tags: polynomials, roots

I did see the explanation [here] ([Whats going on in this quadratic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190931/whats-going-on-in-this-quadratic)). Unfortunately, I am unable to grasp the explanation for why 1 was chosen but also have some additional questions.

1. The substitution $t = sin(x)$ completely changes the graph of the original equation when plotted in [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f33toswadj). The graphs for $f(x) = sin^2(x) -ksin(x) -3$ and $f(t) = t^2-kt-3$ don't align for $0 < x < \pi $.
2. The answer is given as $k < -2$. But this condition is true for $t^2-kt-3$ and not $sin^2(x) -ksin(x) -3$. Since we are asked to find the possible values of $k$ for the original equation: $sin^2(x) -ksin(x) -3$. When a value of $k = -2.1$ is substituted, f(t) > 0 but f(x) < 0 (This can be seen in the graph as well). So how can $k < -2$ be the correct answer ?

Comment: Is it $\sin^2 x -k \sin x - 3$ (in the question) or $\sin^2 x +k \sin x - 3$ (in the title)?

Comment: It's $sin^2(x) - ksin(x) -3$. Sorry I wrote it incorrectly in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

$$f_k(x) = \sin^2 x - k \sin x -3$$ the map defined on $[0, \pi]$. As $f_k(\pi - x) = f_k(x)$, $f_k$ has exactly two roots on $[0,\pi]$ if and only if $f_k$ has exactly one root on $I = [0, \pi/2)$. On $I$, $\sin x$ is stricly increasing from $0$ to $1$. As $x \mapsto \sin x$ is continuous, $f_k$ will have exactly one root on $[0, \pi/2)$ is and only if $g_k(t) = t^2 - kt -3$ has exactly one root on $[0,1)$.

As $g_k(0) = -3 \lt 0$, we must have $g_k(1) \gt 0$, i.e. $k \lt -2$.

Conversely, suppose that $k \lt -2$. We have $g^\prime_k(x) = 2t-k \gt 0$. Which implies that $g_k$ is strictly increasing from $-3$ to $-k-2 \gt 0$ and has only one root on $[0,1)$.

**Conclusion: $k \lt -2$ is the right answer.**

Comment: So, I should be looking at $x = \pi /2$ when $t = 1$ because of the mapping?  Also, I had messed up the sign in the question, I have edited it since, so it should be $k<-2$. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I updated the question and the answer to your question is yes.